# twitter4j.ResponseListImpl cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.List

Tags: java, scala, twitter

I want to convert [twitter4j.ResponseListImpl](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/index.html) to a immutable List in Scala. This should be possible since **ResponseList** extends **java.util.List** interface. I am using the following code:

```
twitter.getHomeTimeline().asInstanceOf[List[Status]].toList
```

Unfortunately I receive the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: twitter4j.ResponseListImpl cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.List
```

Why can't I use **toList** in this case?

Comment: I think this problem is not about toList, it is caused by asInstanceOf cast. Try import scala.collection.JavaConversions._ and work with twitter.getHomeTimeline() as scala List, the conversion should be done implicitly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be simpler than I thought, the right way to convert list of tweets to Scala list is the following:

```
twitter.getHomeTimeline().toList
```

The previous code didn't work because I tried to convert list of tweets to Scala list instead of Java list: **asInstanceOf[List[Status]]** instead of **asInstanceOf[java.utilList[Status]]**